# Accidentally revoked auth for 'Github for Visual Studio' app, added it back and now I cant sign into git hub in VS

Tags: visual-studio, github

I accidentally revoked auth for `Github for Visual Studio` app on this page `https://github.com/settings/applications` > `Authorized OAuth Apps`, added it back and now when I try to sign back in I get the 'Sign in from Browser' Option.
When I try to sign in, it takes me to this localhost `https://localhost:42549/?browser_session_id=XYZ` location and gives me this response.

`This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response. Try running Windows Network Diagnostics. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`